# LINQ select with IEnumerable

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF 4.

I have an `IEnumerable<Type01>` where each of the items (of `Type01`) has an `IEnumerable<Type02>`.

This can explain:

```
Type01 objType01 = ...;
IEnumerable<Type02> en = objType01.allObjType02;
```

I need to do (using LINQ) a select that gives me an `IEnumerable<Type01>` as result, but the "record count" must be the same of the sum of "record count" of all `Type02` items.

For example. For this list:

```
myItem01a
    myItem02a
    myItem02b
myItem01b
    myItem02c
    myItem02d
    myItem02e
```

The select return must be:

```
myItem01a
myItem01a
myItem01b
myItem01b
myItem01b
```

I know how to do this by using old school SQL (JOIN clause). But I'm fairly new to LINQ expressions.
How could it be done?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: I'm getting some problems with FastReport.net when I'm passing IEnumerables as DataSources. FastReport fails when tries to read "complex" structures like objects with children. The only way it worked (for me) was using a "simple" structure, as if it were a DB table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cheat. Use `SelectMany` (or the equivalent multiple `from`s) to iterate over all `Type02`s, but only yield a `Type01` each time round:

```
var repeatedType01s = 
    from t01 in enumerableOfType01s
    from t02 in t01.allObjType02
    select t01;
```

Now `repeatedType01s` is an `IEnumerable<Type01>` with the cardinalities you want.

Comment: My `t01.allObjType02` gives me a **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** error. It happens because `allObjType02` is `Null`, but when a make a "normal" LINQ select and use a foreach to iterate, my `allObjType02` property has a value. Where's the error? I'm using EF4. Thanks.

Comment: I think I know what happened. Sometimes my `t01.allObjType02` is `null`. And it is breaking my code. Is there a way I could "show" the item when this property is null? It's like LEFT JOIN of SQL statements.

Comment: I think I fixed it by putting the second `from` after the where clause that I have here. Thanks. ;)